# Content for this URL is excluded by the server because a no-index attribute

Tags: search, 2007

The crawler crawls everything successfully except the below URL
`http://localhost/alums/lists/324324_classnotes/brown,%20harold%20jr.%20'74` where it gives an error in the crawl log like "Content for this URL is excluded by the server because a no-index attribute".

I do not have any crawl rules setup for any of my content sources.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Michael

**Update:** I checked the source of the page and I found out below tag in it. 
`&lt;META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOHTMLINDEX"/&gt;`

Is it possible if this is blocking the search to work?

Comment: See Anders' comment on the Crawl Rules for the site (In Site Settings->Search Visibility).

Answer (score 1):

Check the source of the page and see if theres a

```
<META name="robots" content= "noindex">
```

Tag in the header. This could be set by the `<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag ID="RobotsMetaTag1" runat="server" />` in the master page.

Have you checked the crawl rules both for the site (Search visibility) and for the pages library (index settings on doclib)?

Answer (score 0):

in crawl rules untick,

"Follow links on the URL without crawling the URL itself"